# Making a custom run Dialog with C or C++?

Tags: c++, c

Well I would like to make a custom run dialog within my program so that the user can test commands without opening it themselves. The only problem is, msdn does not provide any coverage on this. If I cannot make my own custom run dialog and send the data to shell32.dll (where the run dialog is stored) I will settle for the code that can open the run dialog from a button. So far the only information I found is how to open it with VBScript, and I would like to know how to access shell objects within C/C++ directly.

Here is the VBScript if it helps (save as .vbs if you want to see)

```
<script language="VBScript">
    function fnShellFileRunVB()
        dim objShell

        set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        objShell.FileRun

        set objShell = nothing
    end function
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBScript's CreateObject() function just creates an instance of a COM object. You can do exactly the same thing in C++, you just need to read a [tutorial on how to access COM objects using C++](http://progtutorials.tripod.com/COM.htm) first.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a simple RUn dialog is not a big problem (the user interface). The data entered by the user can be run via [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(VS.85).aspx). If you want to call the Run dialog then you should use COM.

Comment: Yes but using shellexecute it says i need more than one parameter, the parameters could be different depending on what command they want to run. I want it to work for every command such as cmd, msconfig, dxdiag, etc.